# Spring MVC change locale with changing direction of page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on spring MVC project . I use spring locale,to change page in English or Arabic . But my problem is in Arabic page because arabic language start with rtl (right to left) . So how can i change page direction on changing locale.

When i click on **Eng|Arabic** , it also change jsp page direction. I have no idea about it, so please anyone can guide me how to achieve this task.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is a matter of css. You have to serve a different style sheets based on locale. One for left to right and other for RTL languages.

Answer (score 9):

You could solve that using the thymeleaf tag **th:attr** ...

and your code will be like the following :

```
<div class="container" th:attr="dir=#{direction}">
```

then in your message_ar.properties file make a field like the follwing

```
direction=rtl
```

and in the other property file

```
direction=ltr
```

so in run time the th:attr tag will bind the direction property to the dir tag and you will be ready to go with your bind data ... you could use this tag for any attribute binding you wish

if you have any question ... don't hesitate to ask